# Reach a windows form title text?

Tags: c#

I wonder how I can reach the title text in a windows form from a reference of the object like this

```
 reference. ??? = "Title one";
```

Help is preciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Text` Property of that form reference object.

```
formrefrence.Text = "New caption";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.Text = "Title one";
```

If this isn't what you mean please provide more details.